# Pad JSON array with JQ to obtain rectangular result

Tags: json, csv, multidimensional-array, jq

I have json that looks like [this](https://jqplay.org/s/xVtQsILfhr)  (jq play in the link), and I want to build csv in the end looking like this (reproducible sample at the bottom).

```
"SO302993",items1,item2,item3.1,item3.2,item3.3, item3.4,...
"SO302994",items1,item2,item3.1,item3.2,       ,        ,...
"SO302995",items1,item2,item3.1,item3.2,item3.3,        ,...
```

item3 elements are in an array and my current solution:

```
.[] | [.number, .item1, item2, item3[]?]
```

gives me this:

```
"SO302993",items1,item2,item3.1,item3.2,item3.3, item3.4,...
"SO302994",items1,item2,item3.1,item3.2,...
"SO302995",items1,item2,item3.1,item3.2,item3.3,...
```

which will create an uneven number of columns in the csv.

I tried adding `.item3[:]?` in a Python flavor-style, but it didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated! And if I wasn't clear do ask to clarify! My snippet and toy data are in the link above.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Mr Simon Mackin",
      "country_of_residence": "Scotland",
      "natures_of_control": [
        "voting-rights-25-to-50-percent-limited-liability-partnership",
        "significant-influence-or-control-limited-liability-partnership"
      ],
      "premises": "4"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Mrs Simonne Mackinni",
      "country_of_residence": "France",
      "natures_of_control": [
        "significant-influence-or-control-limited-liability-partnership"
      ],
      "premises": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

with this query:

```
.items[] | [.name, .country_of_residence, .natures_of_control[]?, .premises] | @csv
```

I get this results

```
"Mr Simon Mackin","Scotland","voting-rights","significant-influence","4"
"Mrs Simonne Mackinni","France","significant-influence","4"
```

But I'd like to get this (second line has extra comma after "significant-influence).

```
"Mr Simon Mackin","Scotland","voting-rights","significant-influence","4"
"Mrs Simonne Mackinni","France","significant-influence",,"4"
```

Comment: Please could you include a [mcve] in the post itself, so we don't have to follow a link, and so the question will still make sense in the future if that link stops working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want a rectangular result, you will have to "pad" the "natures_of_control" array.  Based on the sample input, you will need to "slurp" the input in order to obtain a global maximum.

To pad the array, you could use the helper function:

```
# emit a stream of exactly $n items
def pad($n): range(0;$n) as $i | .[$i];
```

The solution to the problem as posted on jqplay then becomes:

```
([.[] | .items[] | .natures_of_control | length] | max) as $mx
| .[]
| (.active_count) as $active_count
| (.ceased_count) as $ceased_count
| (.links.self | split("/")[2]) as $companyCode
| .items[]
| [$companyCode, $active_count, $ceased_count, .name, .country_of_residence, .nationality, .notified_on, (.natures_of_control | pad($mx))]
| @csv
```

#### Invocation

The appropriate invocation would look like this:

```
jq -sr -f program.jq input.json
```

### Handling missing data

To ignore objects that have no "items" you could tweak the above, e.g. as follows:

```
([.[] | .items[]? | .natures_of_control | length] | max) as $mx
 | .[]
 | select(.items)
 | (.active_count) as $active_count
 | (.ceased_count) as $ceased_count
 | (.links.self | split("/")[2]) as $companyCode
 | .items[]
 | [$companyCode, $active_count, $ceased_count, .name, .country_of_residence, .nationality, .notified_on, (.natures_of_control | pad($mx))]
 | @csv
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I will change the title of the question to reflect the right semantics of how you express my question for others to be able to find it.

Comment: I have a little issue with the fact that the jsonline file actually contains a lot of empty jsons, imagine the following stacked: `{} {} {} {with stuff} ...` I tried to add `?` after the  `.[]` at line 6 of your solution but I get that `jq: error (at <stdin>:5): Cannot iterate over null (null) exit status 5`. Any ideas?